# Something off with \pause in beamer

Tags: beamer, pause

Something is off with `\pause` in my beamer file below. It does not work properly. Any idea why?

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[shrink=10]

\begin{align}
P(Y_i=1) = & \begin{pmatrix} 
n_i \\
y_i \\
\end{pmatrix}\pi_i^{y_i}(1-\pi_i)^{n_i-y_i}  \\ \pause
\mathcal{L} (\boldsymbol{\beta|y}) = & \prod_{i=1}^N 
\begin{pmatrix} 
n_i \\
y_i \\
\end{pmatrix}\pi_i^{y_i}(1-\pi_i)^{n_i-y_i} \\ \pause
= & \prod_{i=1}^N
\begin{pmatrix} 
n_i \\
y_i \\
\end{pmatrix}\Big (\frac{\pi_i}{1-\pi_i} \Big)^{y_i}(1-\pi_i)^{n_i} \\  \pause
\log{\mathcal{L} (\boldsymbol{\beta|y}) } = & \sum_{i=1}^N \Bigg[y_i \log{\Big     (\frac{\pi_i}{1-\pi_i}\Big )} + n_i \log{(1-\pi_i)} + \log \begin{pmatrix} 
n_i \\
y_i \\
\end{pmatrix} \Bigg ] 
\end{align}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Section 23.4 of the manual; `align` doesn't cooperate well with `\pause`.

Comment: The code above perfectly works on Mac, but not on windows. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Sorry, but Windows and I don't get along well.

Comment: Neither do I :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uncovering a displayed multiline numbered formula in `beamer` is a little tricky, as explained in Section **23.4 Uncovering Tagged Formulas Piecewise** of the `beamer` manual; there, you can also find the recommended approach: to use `\uncover` and an empty last line afterwards compensated using a negative vertical space:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[shrink=10]

\begin{align}
\uncover<+->{
   P(Y_i=1) &=  \binom{n_i}{y_i}\pi_i^{y_i}(1-\pi_i)^{n_i-y_i}  \\
} 
\uncover<+->{
  \mathcal{L} (\boldsymbol{\beta\mid y}) &=  \prod_{i=1}^N 
  \binom{n_i}{y_i} \\
}
\uncover<+->{
  \pi_i^{y_i}(1-\pi_i)^{n_i-y_i} 
  &= \prod_{i=1}^N
  \binom{n_i}{y_i}\Bigl(\frac{\pi_i}{1-\pi_i} \Bigr)^{y_i}(1-\pi_i)^{n_i} \\
}
\uncover<+->{
  \log{\mathcal{L} (\boldsymbol{\beta|y}) } &= \sum_{i=1}^N 
    \Biggl[y_i \log{\Bigl(\frac{\pi_i}{1-\pi_i}\Bigr)} 
    + n_i \log{(1-\pi_i)} + \log \binom{n_i}{y_i}\Biggr] \\
}     
\notag
\end{align}
\vskip-1.5em

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

An animation of the result:

[image]

Not related to the question, but I made some other modifications to your code: to use `\binom` instead of `bmatrix` and to use the "lateral" versions `\Biggl`, `\Biggr` instead of just `\Bigg` to guarantee proper space handling.